# Set up "toggle comment" command in slickedit? Add more than one hotkey to a command in slickedit?

Tags: configuration, ide, editor, hotkeys, slickedit

Is there a way to do either of these two things?

> Add hotkey to "toggle comment". By
>   default slickedit seems to have 2
>   separate commands, comment and
>   erase-comment. I wish to have a single
>   hotkey to handle both (similar to how
>   eclipse/netbeans handles it).

█

> Add 2 separate hotkeys to do the same
>   command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SE16 (probably also in previous versions, I didn't check) you'll find a command `toggle-comment` (look in source file box.e). You may bind that to a key.

And the second one is simple: Go to Tools -> Options, select category "Keyboard and Mouse", sub "Key Bindings". Search the command/key you need, and press the button "Add..." to add another key binding.